# How do I compare the value located at an address held within a register with another value?

Tags: assembly, x86, comparison, intel

I have an address held in the ebx and a value held in the eax. They are both unsigned integer values.

How can I compare the values related to these two registers (not the actual address in the ebx).

I have tried:

```
cmp [ebx], eax
```

I though the square brackets meant, in English, *"This variable/register holds a memory address, fetch the value held at this address"*, thus, I thought this would work. However, I get runtime errors at this line of code.

Comment: Is the memory address valid?

Comment: @harold I can't see why it wouldn't be. The address is actually the start of an array but this was first initialised in C++ code (I am using inline assembly)

Comment: How is the value passed from C++ to your assembly routine?

Comment: @James I create the array in C++ using "int array[5];". I then set ebx to the address of the start of the array using "lea ebx, array".

Comment: @harold, am I correct in my use of the square brackets?

Comment: If it helps, the address being held in the ebx is 3407872 at the time of the error

Comment: The brackets are fine, and that address looks plausible at least but there's no way to tell for sure from here. What is the error? Is there any chance it's made on the previous line? Perhaps some surrounding code may help us diagnose this.

Comment: @harold thanks for replying. The runtime error I get is "Unhandled exception at 0x00e32637 in FILENAME.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x003e0000."

Comment: @harold, the line before is "add ebx, 4". This is done as the array is made of ints and thus to cycle through them all I need to adjust the address by 4 each time (This code is part of a loop - but it fails even on the first pass through so isn't loop related yet). Surely I am not going out of my memory bounds by just adjusting the address by 4?

Comment: Ok, I'm afraid that, based on this information, I have to blame the address. 3407872 is 0x340000, and now you have 0x3e0000, that looks to me as though both are just that address but they're different because it's a different run. Alternatively, you did somehow go out of bounds

Comment: @harold Yeah, the addresses change each time I run it. This is also why I am so confused - surely this means I would never go going out of bounds?

Comment: I don't know, perhaps you can post some more code, then I can take a look at that. Or you can try to step through it and see what happens to the address (debuggers can usually do that, but if not, you can throw in some int3's as breakpoints).

Comment: Just ran a debugger on it and noticed this, not sure if this is normal or not (Using Visual Studio Professional). When the array is created, the overall array has the address 0x0034fad8 and every single one of the elements has the same address of -858993460. Firstly, shouldn't each element have a separate address, 4 bytes apart? And also, should the address be negative?

Comment: Are you sure EBX is not being used for something else in the routine? Compilers use the so called "safe registers" in order to implement things like register variables to optimize tight loops and so. Try putting the address of your variable into EDX instead of EBX.

Answer (score 0):

Which runtime error? Segmentation fault?
I still suspect that your address is bad.
It's the only reason I can think of, at the moment, for RUNTIME error.